# Viewing thumbnails of PDF files on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, pdf

How can I view thumbnails of PDF files on Windows XP?

Answer (score 2):

PDF files show a thumbnail automatically on my computer (Win XP) and all I have is Adobe Reader.

Comment: Yep,once you have adobe reader installed it'll let you see the pdf files in thumbnail view

Comment: that's depend on the version of adobe reader ... methinks